# Servlet and Hibernate - won't open the session

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I have this DAO class, which connects with the database via Hibernate:

```
public class ChartDAO {

public static ChartData getChartData(){
    Session session = null;
    List data;
    try {
        try {
            session = HibUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            data = session.createQuery("FROM ChartData").list();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            data = new ArrayList();
            data.add(new ChartData());
        }
    } finally {
        session.disconnect();
        session.close();
        try {
            HibUtil.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ChartData chartData = (ChartData) data.get(0);
    return chartData;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ChartData cd = getChartData();
} 
}
```

When I run the main method, in which i invoke `getChartData()`, everything works fine (checked in debugger - the session gets opened and the data is being retrieved).

However, when I tried to call the same method from the servlet, the data is not being retrieved. I checked with the debugger - it "freezes" for a while when attempting to open the hibernate session and then immediately jumps to the 'finally' block.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: Below is my HibUtil:

```
public class HibUtil {

private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Throwable ex) { 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void close() throws Exception{
    if(serviceRegistry!= null) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE: This is the Apache Tomcat Log when I Try to call the method from the servlet:

```
mar 25, 2014 6:42:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DataProvider] in context with path [/SHJS] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mb.DataProvider.processRequest(DataProvider.java:53)
    at org.mb.DataProvider.doGet(DataProvider.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: do you get any stack trace ?

Comment: you have not added catch block to large try block.try to debugg using that and adding a stacktrace there

Comment: I checked that, by adding the catch after a large try block. It doesn't throw catch any exception (none is being thrown).

Comment: show your hibernateUtil

Comment: you gets error when you call getChartData from servelt rite

Comment: Print the value of session you might be getting it null ,also check WEB.xml for servlet maaping

Comment: YES, the session is NULL when I try to call the method from the SERVLET. But it is NOT NULL whenever I call the method from ANYWHERE ELSE!

Comment: show your servelt you might be doing somthing wrong in that

Comment: in doGet:
...
ChartData cd = ChartDAO.getChartData();

Comment: WHEREVER else I paste that code - it works like a charm. But NEVER in a servlet.

It doesn't make sense.

Comment: rest work you doing same ?creating session and trasctin and connection.what about servelt.jar and web.xml ?you ceked?

Comment: try to use  getCurrentSession instead openSession()

Comment: No success. I don't think you get where my problem is..

Comment: Such a mess of a question. Basically the problem description should be: if I run this code from a standalone java application ("main"), things work. If I run it from a web application I deploy to Tomcat, it doesn't work. So the problem is in the deployment of that web application, like a configuration file is missing or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

create Connection using session

```
 Connection connection     = session.connection();
```

then create your query using connection.as you are not creating connection so it might be not working. 
Also you can use `Annotation Configuration` 
like this

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

and call this

```
Session session  = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

to make session.then transaction and then connection and so on.this worked fine for me you can try.

Comment: I can't use create connection while I can't even open the session!
The thing is, that the session get created succesfully from ANYWHERE (any method, any class)... besides calling it from the servlet :(

Comment: yeah create session first then connection,i mentionaed make session then session.conncetion

Comment: But it doesn't change anything - the 'session' still won't be created when I call this method from a servlet (but the problem wont appear when I call that method from anywhere else).

Comment: can you show the modified code?it sometimes happnes that you session clashes with the default session.as we have session from Http and Map also.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```